# Wordpress breaks CSS hover slider

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a pure CSS mouseover slider fully functional here http://jsfiddle.net/gU4sw/13/ .

When I add this code to my wordpress [page](http://bit.ly/GJQycs), it doesn't work... :(

Can someone please check to see if there a quick fix or explanation for this?

P.S: By the way, I was able to install the same exact slider code on [another](http://bit.ly/GVlGq8) wordpress installation without any problems, yet it doesn't work for this [installation](http://bit.ly/GJQycs) for some reason :(

Comment: Css rules missing in wordpress css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css rules are missing your wordpress css thats the main issue you are facing. In fiddle the css is working on hover but in wordpress css its not present try to check you css again.

Update:

In you css rule is not closed at line 499. right curly brace `}` is missing thats why below this rule all css is ignoring.

```
.abul { list-style-image:url(/wp-content/themes/Chameleon/images/barrow.gif);
```

try to close this and see whether css will work or not. I have tested in FF firebug your desired css is not including.

Comment: I checked the page with firebug and I see the css presented on the very bottom of style.css (starts at string 511)

Comment: man I feel so stupid, I erased the brace when was pasting css for slider.. Thanks so much, you the best!